# If I don’t use a tag in a query, does this decrease cardinality?

Tags: database, time-series, influxdb, cardinality

I have the following problem with InfluxDb: it overwires values with the same tag set and timestamp (a terrible design choice in my view).

Now to sidestep this in a cost effective manner one idea is to make a tag (e.g. `value_id`) which is unique and constantly increasing.

I know this will bloat cardinality to a point where query time will be super slow.

My question is: if I don’t use this random tag (`value_id`) in my query, but have it in the db, will this still-affect the speed of my queries?

If it does not it sounds like a “solution” to my problem.

P.S. I am aware that adding a nanosecond or arbitrary tag are two "solutions" suggested by [InfluxDB](https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/write-data/best-practices/duplicate-points/), but neither sounds good and neither work reliably without a large cost.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your use-case and why you need to write different values with the same time and tagset?

To answer your question: yes, this is damage your write and query time.

InfluxDB has a Seriesfile that stores a mapping if your series key to a unique identifier. This lookup and potential write to the Seriesfile happens on every write and read. The biggest this file gets, the slower these operations get.

It's not actually cardinality from a query POV that is bad, TSI enables billions of series; however the Seriesfile hasn't been optimised for these workloads yet.

Comment: Okay, so that’s not a solution then. An example would be some high frequency data where I store the timestamp of the data source. This timestamp can be provided with lower time precision thus resulting in the issue I have.

Comment: A second example is when a value is being revised (which happens with low frequency data mostly). How would I handle revisions? Note I don't know it's a revision from the source, nor do I know which revision it is (there can be multiple).
The only way I know would be to see if such value exists and add some tag value to it if it does. But that involves reading before writing each value. Do you have any propositions on how to solve such issues?